# Generating a random grid of connected paths

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate a random grid of connected paths. The image below shows how far I've managed to get it:

[image]

The rules that the grid needs to adhere to are the following:

1. all the paths must connect to each other in some way but there can be dead ends
2. there can be no blocks that have no connections (i.e. can't be reached)
3. the blocks on the edge must have paths that point inward, not outward.

As you can see in my image, my code isn't quite right, but I can't find the error.

Here is a fiddle with the code: [jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/jz5sfr00/1](http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/jz5sfr00/1)

But I think my mistake is in this function:

```
 function linkAll() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            //link up to each other
            var count = 0;
            if ((x > 0) && (y > 0)) {
                if (hz[x - 1][y].right) {
                    hz[x][y].left = 1;

                } else count++;

                if (hz[x][y - 1].bottom) {
                    hz[x][y].top = 1;

                } else count++;
            }
            if ((x < 9) && (y < 9)) {
                if (hz[x + 1][y].left) {
                    hz[x][y].right = 1;

                } else count++;

                if (hz[x][y + 1].top) {
                    hz[x][y].bottom = 1;

                } else count++;
            }
            if (count == 4) {
                var newPath = getDirection(getRandomInt(0, 3));
                if (newPath == 'top') {
                    hz[x][y - 1].bottom = 1
                    hz[x][y].top = 1;
                } else if (newPath == 'left') {
                    hz[x - 1][y].right = 1;
                    hz[x][y].left = 1;
                } else if (newPath == 'bottom') {
                    hz[x][y + 1].top = 1;
                    hz[x][y].bottom = 1;
                } else if (newPath == 'right') {
                    hz[x + 1][y].left = 1;
                    hz[x][y].right = 1;
                }
            }
        } //end for (y)
    } //end for (x)
}
```

UPDATE:
I realised that I confused the `x` and `y` values of the array. They should have been swopped.

So I added a `linkEdges()` function so that the edge blocks all link together:

```
function linkEdges(){
    for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++){

            if((x==0) && (y > 0) && (y < 9)){  

                if(hz[0][y-1].right){
                    //console.log(x + ' ' + y + ' y-1 = 1');
                    //console.log('Inside (y-1) ');
                    //console.log(hz[x][y]);
                    if (hz[0][y].left != null) 
                    {
                        hz[0][y].left = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            if ((y==0) && (x > 0)){
                if(hz[x-1][0].bottom){
                    if(hz[x][0].top  != null)
                        hz[x][0].top = 1;
                }
            }

            if ((y==9) && (x < 9) && (x > 0)){
                if(hz[x+1][9].top){
                    if(hz[x][9].bottom != null)
                        hz[x][9].bottom = 1;
                }
            }

            if ((x==9) && (y < 9)){
                if(hz[9][y+1].left){
                    if(hz[9][y].right != null)
                        hz[9][y].right = 1;
                }
            }

        } //end for(y)
    }//end for(x)
}
```

I also updated the `linkAll()` function:

```
function linkAll(){
    for(var x=0; x < 9; x++){
        for(var y=0; y < 9; y++){
            //link up to each other
            var count = 0;

            if((x > 0) && (y > 0)){
                if(hz[x-1][y].bottom){                  
                    hz[x][y].top = 1;

                }
                else count++;

                if(hz[x][y-1].right){
                    hz[x][y].left = 1;

                }
                else count++;   
            }

            if((x < 9) && (y < 9)){
                if(hz[x+1][y].top){
                    hz[x][y].bottom = 1;    

                }
                else count++;

                if(hz[x][y+1].left){
                    hz[x][y].right = 1;

                }
                else count++;
            }


            if(count == 4){
                //console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: '+y);
                var newPath = getDirection(getRandomInt(0, 3));
                //console.log(newPath);

                if(newPath == 'top'){
                    hz[x][y-1].right = 1
                    hz[x][y].left = 1;
                }
                else if(newPath == 'left'){
                    hz[x-1][y].bottom = 1;
                    hz[x][y].top = 1;
                }
                else if(newPath == 'bottom'){
                    hz[x][y+1].left = 1;        
                    hz[x][y].right = 1;             
                }
                else if(newPath == 'right'){
                    hz[x+1][y].top = 1; 
                    hz[x][y].bottom = 1;
                }

            }
        }//end for (y)
    }//end for (x)
}
```

My grid now looks like this:
[image]

I just don't know how to connect those last few edges. I think it has something to do with my `linkEdges()` function.

Comment: Nice work, would be better if your images work, so we can test it properly ourselves

Comment: Yeah, do you know of a site that let's me do that?

Comment: Never mind, sorted it for you : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/jz5sfr00/1/

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you clarify point #3? for example is top-right corner of your image a valid block(ignoring  the fact it is not connected)

Comment: Yes, the one on the top-right is valid. To put it this way, no block on the top can have top paths, none on the left can have left paths etc. And the top-left corner block can't have a top or a left path.